# To retrieve the response of CURL

Tags: xml, parsing, curl

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

the result of the above expression is as follows

> HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2016 11:28:13 GMT Set-Cookie:
>   JSESSIONID=16v102xwvaga31326wppzq43xp;Path=/ Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970
>   00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/xml Content-Length: 193
>
> UserAlreadyExistsExceptionCould
>   not create new userJohn123

But I am not able to retrieve the XML values. How can I retrieve the XML values?

Comment: sorry the result displayed is like  "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><error><exception>UserAlreadyExistsException</exception><message>Could not create new user</message><ressource>John123</ressource></error>"

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 possibilities here, Delete the created user via curl or your back end.

log in as the created user or create a new user account. there will be API hook points which will allow you to fetch info of the created account i believe.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But maybe I did not put the question to you properly.I have got the response like "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><error><exception>UserAlreadyExistsException</exception><messa‌​ge>Could not create new user</message><ressource>John123</ressource></error>"  from CURL..And I want to retrieve the above values b parsing the output.How is that possible

Answer (score 0):

> How can I retrieve the XML values

It's a very simply. Example on `PHP` (I see you use this programming language):

```
<?php

// It's your XML-string ($result)    
$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>'
        . '<error>'
        . '<exception>UserAlreadyExistsException</exception>'
        . '<message>Could not create new user</message>'
        . '<ressource>John123</ressource>'
        . '</error>';

if($xml = simplexml_load_string($result)) {
    echo "<p>Exception: " . $xml->exception . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Message: " . $xml->message . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Ressource: " . $xml->ressource . "</p>";    
}

?>
```

Result:

> Exception: UserAlreadyExistsException
>
> Message: Could not create new user
>
> Ressource: John123